# Is drawing UIBezierPath part of Model View or Controller in MVC

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, code-organization

I would like to create a swift class that handles drawing some UIBezierPath and also redraw when user modify the path via gestures.   I have 3 questions.

- Is drawing UIBezierPath belong Model View or Controller?
- Is it a good idea to create such a class or just put all code inside viewController.swift instead?
- Should I ever make classes for View or Controller as the tutorial I saw(stanford ios) seems to only create separate class for Model functions.

Comment: If your drawing thing is generic (aka, can be used in other places) it goes inside a "helper" class. If it's specific for that single view, it goes into the View code.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion:

- Model: Store data of the path in the Model class, like array of points.
- Utility/Helper: Create some painting methods in a utility class, like PaintHelper. Input is the data of the path. So you can use it in other projects.
- Controller: call to get data from model, then call painting methods. Then get final result and display/reset UI.